# Is it considered "bad practice" to use "@" to avoid errors?

Tags: php

Is using `@` to repress errors considered bad practice? Take this code for an example:

```
...
$an_array = false;

if (something) $an_array = array("key" => "value); 

if (array_key_exists("key", $an_array)) ...
```

In my structure it can be, that `an_array` is still `false` when I want to use `array_key_exists()` on it. Is it considered bad practice to do: `@array_key_exists()`? Shall I use `if (is_array($an_array) AND array_key_exists(...))` instead?

Comment: _Is it considered “bad practice” to use “@” do avoid errors?_ Yes it is.

Comment: thanks, then i wont use it

Comment: It definitely is. I'm pretty sure error suppression in any language is bad practice.

Comment: You can also do `$an_array = array();` which loosely evaluates to false.

Comment: AbraCadaver, THANKS, good idea. didnt even come up with this.

Comment: Or even cast `array_key_exists("key", (array)$an_array)`, but it's better to give what you need or test for expected.

Comment: Here's a better way to do it: error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);    ;)

Comment: @TimHinz I don't know why that is better. Considering `@` sets error reporting for the line to 0, it does effectively the same as `error_reporting(0);` limited to the line it is on.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois it was sarcasm... lol